# Enable input from keyboard in C# process after redirecting standard input and writing to cmd programatically

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd

I am writing a C# Windows Forms app, which starts a cmd process, and I set RedirectStandardInput to true before calling Process.start, in order to write to cmd programatically. but after the application writes to cmd I want to enable again keyboard input, because after the first command is executed, I cannot input with keyboard to the same cmd window. Here is my code:

```
Process pr=new Process();
pr.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pr.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = currentFolder;
pr.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pr.Start();
pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(stringToWrite);
```

Is there any way to enable keyboard input again in the "Same" cmd window?

I tried setting `pr.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;` after calling `pr.StandardInput.WriteLine(stringToWrite);` but it didn't work, so what's the solution?

Comment: I'm wonder why are you doing this because I'm thinking in a lot of different ways to do this without so much trouble

Comment: Just run `cmd /k myfirstcommand` without all that stuff?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Thanks, but I might need to execute two different commands, would that still work?